# Can I move my logo to center of top menu?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I need help for modify my site. I'm new to this, please help me:)

Can I move my logo to center of very top menu? You can check my site. My site is [here](http://www.samgyoyu.com).

You can see the 4 item, I would like to move my logo between 'life' and 'story'.

Thank you and have a nice day!

---

**Lukas's answer:** Just create another `<li>` element inside the `<ul id="secondary-nav">` and move the `<div id="branding">` or better only the `<a>` inside. Probbaly you should also remove the float:left on the logo.

**= Yes I understand and I test this on F12(developer tool)**, It works great! But my problem is **I don't know where I can create `<li>`.** I find `<ul id="secondary-nav">` on F12. I guess I have to edit "header.php". Am I right? Can I know exactly where? Please help me:)

**JSfiddle:**http://jsfiddle.net/user3543818/UNnYp/2/ (You can see "header.php" and CSS for top menu)

Comment: Can you add your imagelogo as the text within your main menu?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can , if you want give us the code but : 
put youe logo in new div and make it padding : 0 auto 
or you can put it as your screen old you 
please send us the code

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. Which code do you want? I can give you:)

Comment: Sorry for late! This is my JSfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/user3543818/UNnYp/2/ You can check it:) Thank you for help me. And I update my question!

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell with just a link, but it looks like you are using a template you purchased. If that is the case, a lot of purchasable templates have settings within the wordpress dashboard that will allow you to customize certain parts of the look-and-feel. Logo placement is often one of those editable features.

A code example would make it easier to give you an exact answer, but in this case it seems like you can simply add your logo as a menu item in between life and story, so it will be displayed in the center of the list. This can be done through your wordpress dashboard as well, or you can hardcode it in the template.

Answer (score 0):

if you want your logo top of your site, you can use float: inherit;
if you want it exactly between the menu items, you must define your logo as a li (list item) and put it between 'life' and 'story'.

Comment: Hi Tamer, I understand and I test this on F12(developer tool). It works great but the problem is I don't know where I can create new li. Maybe header.php? Can you give me a more advice? Thank you:) And I update my question. You can see my JSfiddle:)

Comment: Oh I'm really sorry. It's my first time to use JSfiddle. I want to fix it but I can't use computer now:( And please know me which CSS, PHP, HTML do you need.

Comment: I sent you an email:) Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just create another `<li>` element inside the `<ul id="secondary-nav">` and move the `<div id="branding">` or better only the `<a>` inside. Probbaly you should also remove the float:left on the logo.

Comment: Hi Lukas, Thank you for answer:) Yes I understand and I test this on F12(developer tool), It works great! But my problem is I don't know where I can create <li>. I find <ul id="secondary-nav"> on F12. I guess I have to edit "header.php". Am I right? Can I know exactly where? Please help me:) I update my question. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
.yourlogo{
    margin-right: 7px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer:) I mean, I would like to move my logo down to between 'Life' and 'Story'.

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle from your menu? i tried to access the jsfiddle that you sent, but you forgot to add the html.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know exactly about HTML. You can use F12. And please tell me where I can fine HTML:) I'm sorry.

Comment: You shouldn't buy an template, is more easier to do your own template and learn html and css, than buy a template. Btw, its really hard to help you here, but i will try, i saw your website code, you can do the same thing to, you have a file  called simplemag-child/style.css?ver=3.9.1 and when you access this file, if you press control f and you search for logo, you will find the logo code, try too change some margins values there, i really can't help you more than this